# Changing query from access SQL to SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created this query in Microsoft access and I am trying to run it in SQL Server 2012 but I am getting several errors I have tried a few different ways to fix it but I still cant get it working

```
SELECT Choose(Iif(IsNull([TaxCodeChangeTypeID]),0,
                   [TaxCodeChangeTypeID])+1,
                   'UNKNOWN',
                   'UPLIFT',
                   'PAPERP6',
                   'PAPERP9',
                   'P453',
                   'P46',
                   'HMRC',
                   'DPSP6',
                   'DPSP9',
                   'P46(Pen)',
                   'P46(Expat)') AS [Tax Code Change Type]
FROM EeBals
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: `ISNULL` takes two parameters in SQL Server: The first being the expression to check, the second being the value to return if it is null.

Comment: `ISNULL` works differently in SQL Server than it does in ACCESS, in ACCESS it returns true if the values is null, in SQL Server it works like the ANSI SQL `COALESCE`, but only with 2 values

Comment: @Psychemaster what do you suggest would be the best way to write it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not being able to test it, but as it seems `ISNULL` should be the only issue here.

In `MS Access`, `ISNULL` returns true if the checked value is in fact null, but in `SQL Server` it works like a `COALESCE` (but only taking 2 instead of unlimited parameters) returning the second value if the first was null.

`CHOOSE` and `Iif` should work similarily to MS Access in SQL Server.
I would simply replace `IsNull([TaxCodeChangeTypeID])` with `[TaxCodeChangeTypeID] IS NULL`

```
SELECT Choose
    (
        Iif
        (
            [TaxCodeChangeTypeID] IS NULL,
            0,
            [TaxCodeChangeTypeID]
        )+1,

        'UNKNOWN','UPLIFT','PAPERP6','PAPERP9','P453','P46','HMRC','DPSP6','DPSP9','P46(Pen)','P46(Expat)'
    ) AS [Tax Code Change Type]
FROM EeBals
```

Note: this only applies to `SQL Server` since the version `2012`, before that neither `IIF` nor `CHOOSE` were present in either standard `SQL Server` or `SQL Server Express`

PS: of course the whole `IIf(...)+1` can now be avoided and be a little more beautified [as GarethD also mentioned in his post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25445018/2186023) by writing `ISNULL([TaxCodeChangeTypeID], 0) + 1` instead.

Comment: This does work on SQL Server 2012 express edition, did you test on 2008? Choose and Iif were both only introduced in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @GarethD yep true, thx for mentioning that, I included that in my post.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, `ISNULL` in Access takes a single parameter and returns a boolean value depending on whether the parameter passed is null, in SQL Server ISNULL takes two arguments, the first is the value to check, and the second is the value to return if the value is null, so your line:

```
Iif(IsNull([TaxCodeChangeTypeID]),0, [TaxCodeChangeTypeID])+1
```

Needs to be replaced with

```
ISNULL([TaxCodeChangeTypeID], 0) + 1
```

To acheive the same thing. Making your full query:

```
SELECT  CHOOSE(ISNULL([TaxCodeChangeTypeID], 0) + 1,
                   'UNKNOWN',
                   'UPLIFT',
                   'PAPERP6',
                   'PAPERP9',
                   'P453',
                   'P46',
                   'HMRC',
                   'DPSP6',
                   'DPSP9',
                   'P46(Pen)',
                   'P46(Expat)') AS [Tax Code Change Type]
FROM EeBals
```